# onenote javascript API addSectionGroup fails

Tags: javascript, office-js, onenote

I'd like to add a section group to a Notebook using the JavaScript API function `addSectionGroup`.

To keep things as simple as possible, I copy the code from the [official reference](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/onenote/notebook). The `sectionGroup` is created however the following error is thrown:

```
Debug info: {
  "code":"GeneralException",
  "message":"Something went wrong. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.",
  "errorLocation":"Notebook.addSectionGroup"
}
```

This is bad, because all commands queued up after the `addSectionGroup` (which are not part of this example but will be eventually) are being ignored.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

For convenience, this is the source:

```js
OneNote.run(function (context) {

    // Gets the active notebook.
    var notebook = context.application.getActiveNotebook();

    // Queue a command to add a new section group.
    var sectionGroup = notebook.addSectionGroup("Sample section group");

    // Queue a command to load the new section group.
    sectionGroup.load();

    // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log("New section group name is " + sectionGroup.name);
        });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried requesting it load the `name` property using `sectionGroup.load("name")` instead of `sectionGroup.load();`?

Comment: i tried. result is the same.

Comment: i did not find a solution, only a workaround: `notebook.addSectionGroup(...) ... return context.sync().catch().then(...)` where the `catch()` catches the error and in the following `then()` API commands can continue